# AppleScript select element where only the label/text attribute is set

Tags: ios, macos, keyboard, applescript, keyboard-maestro

I want to click each of the three console buttons in the debugger of  IntelliJ. There is no inbuilt shortcut and the click at found image within Keyboard Maestro was not working.

Based on this I have constructed the following AppleScript with the help of ChatGPT but am getting no luck

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "WebStorm-EAP"
        -- Wait until the application is ready
        repeat until exists (windows)
            delay 0.5
        end repeat

        -- Variable to store the found element
        set theElement to missing value

        -- Iterate through each window
        repeat with theWindow in windows
            -- Try to find the target element in the current window
            try
                -- Get all elements that could potentially be the target
                set allElements to UI elements of theWindow

                -- Iterate through all elements to find the target
                repeat with anElement in allElements
                    -- Check for elements with a title or description that matches
                    if value of anElement is "Debugger Console" or label of anElement is "Debugger Console" then
                        set theElement to anElement
                        exit repeat
                    end if
                end repeat

                if theElement is not missing value then
                    exit repeat
                end if

            on error
                -- Ignoring errors to continue searching in other windows
            end try
        end repeat

        -- Check if the element was found and perform action
        if theElement is not missing value then
            click theElement
        else
            display alert "Element not found."
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

[image: intellij buttons]
[image: accessiblity tree]
[image: accesibility labels]